# How to turn off silent = 1 in xgboost?

Tags: r, xgboost

I am trying to train a xgboost model and the traing seem to work but I can't manage to set the parameter silent to 0, that is printing the training-iterations. I use the code below:

```
param <- list(max_depth = 2, eta = 0.005, nthread = 2, objective = "multi:softprob", eval_metric = "auc", num_class = 3, verbose = 2, silent = 0)

xgb.train(param, data = test_matrix_1, nrounds = 10, print_every_n = 1)
```

And gets this in return:

```
##### xgb.Booster
raw: 12.2 Kb 
call:
 xgb.train(params = param, data = test_matrix_1, nrounds = 10, 
  print_every_n = 1)
params (as set within xgb.train):
 max_depth = "2", eta = "0.005", nthread = "2", objective = "multi:softprob", eval_metric = "auc", num_class = "3", verbose = "2", silent = "0", silent = "1"
xgb.attributes:
 niter
callbacks:
 cb.print.evaluation(period = print_every_n)
niter: 10
```

Comment: Is there any option `silent` in xgboost in R? I think you should play with different values of `verbose`.

Comment: I think you just need to ignore `silent` option in `param`. `?xgboost` says that "_silent 0 means printing running messages, 1 means silent mode. Default: 0_".

Comment: Sais so in page 21
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xgboost/xgboost.pdf

and I have tried all three settings for verbose, without luck unfortunatly, but thanks for the tip

Comment: Yes @Prem, the problem I have is that my silent default seem to be 1 rather than 0

Comment: Can you check after adding `verbose = 2` in `xgb.train` instead of `param` list?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I tried, unfortunatly no luck with that either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** of all you need to remove `verbose` from `param` list if you want to turn off `silent = 1` (refer `?xgboost`).

**Secondly** you need `watchlist` parameter since you are concerned of observing eval_metric while learning. It has the ability to learn on the first dataset and test its model on the second one (for more info refer `?xgboost`). e.g.

```
watchlist <- list(train=dtrain, test=dtest)
```

Now a sample implementation can be done in below manner -

```
library(xgboost)

#sample data
data(agaricus.train, package='xgboost')
data(agaricus.test, package='xgboost')

dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(agaricus.train$data, label = agaricus.train$label)
dtest  <- xgb.DMatrix(agaricus.test$data, label = agaricus.test$label)
watchlist <- list(train=dtrain, test=dtest)

#training XGBoost model 
param <- list(max_depth = 2, eta = 1, nthread = 2, 
              objective = "binary:logistic", eval_metric = "auc", eval_metric="error")
fit <- xgb.train(param, data=dtrain, nrounds=10, watchlist=watchlist, verbose = 2)
```

Comment: Thanks alot @Prem, it almost worked, I get print such as:
[15:03:37] amalgamation/../src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 12 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=4

but still no eval_metric...

Comment: First of all, I'm very sorry for my late response, I'm very greatful for your help, unfortunatly, this did not do the trick.

But I managed to find away around it though, through using the xgboost function and Csparsematrix from the Matrix-package.

Comment: Great that you found an answer. You may be interested in posting that as an answer so that others can be benefitted if trapped in similar kind of maze running in future. BTW _both function's implementation are same. `xgb.train` is an advanced interface & `xgboost` provides a simpler interface._

Comment: Specifying the "watchlist" solved the problem for me. So I think this answer should be accepted @AllanA

Answer (score 1):

You dont use the `silent` parameter in R.
you use the `verbose` parameter.

Here are examples of `verbose = 0, 1 or 2`

```
# verbose = 0, no message
bst <- xgboost(data = dtrain, max.depth = 2, eta = 1, nthread = 2, nround = 2, objective = "binary:logistic", verbose = 0)

# verbose = 1, print evaluation metric
bst <- xgboost(data = dtrain, max.depth = 2, eta = 1, nthread = 2, nround = 2, objective = "binary:logistic", verbose = 1)

## [0]  train-error:0.046522
## [1]  train-error:0.022263

# verbose = 2, also print information about tree
bst <- xgboost(data = dtrain, max.depth = 2, eta = 1, nthread = 2, nround = 2, objective = "binary:logistic", verbose = 2)

## [11:41:01] amalgamation/../src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 6 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=2
## [0]  train-error:0.046522
## [11:41:01] amalgamation/../src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 4 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=2
## [1]  train-error:0.022263
```

Answer (score 1):

This workaround, worked for me:

Converted the data as a list consisting of both label and data as CsparseMatrix from the Matrix package.

```
test_matrix_3 <- list(data = as(training_data, "CsparseMatrix"), label = label)
```

After that this function worked fine.

```
xgboost(data = test_matrix_3$data, label = test_matrix_3$label, 
                 max.depth = 4, eta = 1, nthread = 2, nround = 500, objective = "multi:softmax", num_class = 3, eval.error = "auc")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `options(warn=-1, echo=FALSE, verbose=FALSE)`, you can also view other options in `.Options`